# Why I can't correctly extract data from XML field into this JDBC query?

Tags: java, xml, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I have the following query performed on an Oracle database:

```
SELECT
'ENELSERV' as CODCLIENTE, 
'SL' as SOTTOSISTEMA,
'DD01' as ACCOUNT, 
concat('0',to_char(sysdate,'DDD')) as Progressivo,

substr(xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT (
      '//cbc:IssueDate/text()') 
      .getStringVal (),1,4) as ANNO,
xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT (
      '//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyName/cbc:Name/text()')
      .getStringVal () as DESTINATARIO,
concat(concat(
xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT (
      '//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PhysicalLocation/cac:Address/cbc:StreetName/text()'
      ).getStringVal () 
,' '),xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT (
      '//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PhysicalLocation/cac:Address/cbc:BuildingNumber/text()'
      ).getStringVal ())        
      AS INDIRIZZO,
xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT (
      '//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PhysicalLocation/cac:Address/cbc:PostalZone/text()'
      ).getStringVal () as CAP,
xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT (
      '//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PhysicalLocation/cac:Address/cbc:CountrySubentityCode/text()'
      ).getStringVal () AS PROVINCIA,
xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT (
      '//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PhysicalLocation/cac:Address/cbc:CityName/text()'
      ).getStringVal () AS COMUNE,

xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT (
      '//in:Invoice/cbc:ID/text()') 
      .getStringVal () AS ACCTUM,
      pdf
from coda_tx c, documenti_tx d
WHERE   C.FK_TIPO_DOC = 99
        AND C.FK_STATO = 1

        AND C.FK_PIVA_MITTENTE = '05779711000'
        AND C.PK_CODA = D.PFK_CODA
        AND C.CANALE='STA'
```

As you can see this query select come field from DB tables and some field from an XML file that represent a specific field of a table.

When I perform it into **Oracle SQL Developer** it works fine and I correctly retrieve the values into the XML as I expect.

Then I implement a DAO class (that use JDBC) into my Java code that perform the previous query, this one:

```
public void getListaFatturePDF(String partitaIva) {
    System.out.println("INTO ottieniListaFatturePDF()");

    Blob blobFibalPdf;
    String sql;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    sb.append("SELECT 'ENELSERV' as CODCLIENTE, 'SL' as SOTTOSISTEMA, 'DD01' as ACCOUNT, ");
    sb.append("concat('0',to_char(sysdate,'DDD')) as Progressivo, ");
    sb.append("substr(xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT ('//cbc:IssueDate/text()').getStringVal (),1,4) as ANNO, ");
    sb.append("xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT ('//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyName/cbc:Name/text()').getStringVal () as DESTINATARIO, ");
    sb.append("concat(concat(xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT ('//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PhysicalLocation/cac:Address/cbc:StreetName/text()').getStringVal () ");
    sb.append(",' '),xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT ('//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PhysicalLocation/cac:Address/cbc:BuildingNumber/text()').getStringVal ()) AS INDIRIZZO, ");
    sb.append("xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT ('//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PhysicalLocation/cac:Address/cbc:PostalZone/text()').getStringVal () as CAP, ");
    sb.append("xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT ('//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PhysicalLocation/cac:Address/cbc:CountrySubentityCode/text()').getStringVal () AS PROVINCIA, ");
    sb.append("xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT ('//cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PhysicalLocation/cac:Address/cbc:CityName/text()').getStringVal () AS COMUNE, ");
    sb.append("xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT ('//in:Invoice/cbc:ID/text()').getStringVal () AS ACCTUM, ");
    sb.append("pdf ");
    sb.append("from coda_tx c, documenti_tx d ");
    sb.append("WHERE   C.FK_TIPO_DOC = 99 ");
    sb.append("AND C.FK_STATO = 1 ");
    sb.append("AND C.PK_CODA = D.PFK_CODA ");
    sb.append("AND C.CANALE='STA' ");
    sb.append("AND C.FK_PIVA_MITTENTE = '");
    sb.append(partitaIva);
    sb.append("'");

    sql = sb.toString();

    try {
        statment = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statment.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("ResultSet obtained");

        //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        while(rs.next()){
            // Retrieve by column name:

            String codCliente = rs.getString("CODCLIENTE");
            String sottosistema = rs.getString("SOTTOSISTEMA");
            String account = rs.getString("ACCOUNT");
            String progressivo = rs.getString("Progressivo");
            String anno = rs.getString("ANNO");
            String destinatario = rs.getString("DESTINATARIO");
            String indirizzo = rs.getString("INDIRIZZO");
            String cap = rs.getString("CAP");
            String provincia = rs.getString("PROVINCIA");
            String comune = rs.getString("COMUNE");
            String acctum = rs.getString("ACCTUM");
            Blob pdf = rs.getBlob("PDF");

            //int pfk_coda = rs.getInt("PFK_CODA");
            //Blob blobCurrentPdf = rs.getBlob("PDF");


            // Display values:
            System.out.println("codCliente: " + codCliente);
            System.out.println("sottosistema: " + sottosistema);
            System.out.println("account: " + account);
            System.out.println("progressivo: " + progressivo);
            System.out.println("anno: " + anno);
            System.out.println("destinatario: " + destinatario);
            System.out.println("indirizzo: " + indirizzo);
            System.out.println("cap: " + cap);
            System.out.println("provincia: " + provincia);
            System.out.println("comune: " + comune);
            System.out.println("acctum: " + acctum);

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");


            //System.out.println("PFK_CODA: " + pfk_coda);

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}
```

The problem is that I have no problem for the values into standard DB cells (the fields: **CODCLIENTE**, **SOTTOSISTEMA** and **ACCOUNT**) but for all the others fields retrieved from the XML I have an empty string as value.

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Comment: @AlexPoole mmm, please can you show me a code snippet related what have I to try, I will be very gratefull

Comment: @AlexPoole Tnx, tomorrow morning I will try when I come back to office

Comment: @AlexPoole dont' works :-(

Comment: I didn't say it was a *good* guess. Next thing I'd look at is whether your JDBC driver version is compatible with your database version. But I also wonder if the namespaces are being lost, which is causing no match for the extracts. It might be better to use XQuery anyway.

Comment: @AlexPoole BINGO I change the JDBC driver into my project using the ojdbc.jar file that is into the Oracle SQL Developer installation directory (I think that is an older version but it wors). But why in this way works? It seems that now I am using an oldest version of the ojdbc.jar file, why this features seems not be maintened into the actual version? what could be the problem? maybe also the db is old and could exist some neamespace problem?

Comment: There are compatibility restrictions between JDBC and DB versions; see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/getsta.htm#JJDBC28046) or the equivalent for your DB version, and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03). You can get various weird effects from a mismatch. And older DB with a newer driver is usually OK but there are still limits. Without knowing either version number it's hard to guess really.

Comment: @AlexPoole ok tnx very much. Do you know where I can find this compatibility matrix?

Comment: I [linked to it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03) in an edit to my previous comment. For other, older, versions you'd need to check the DB docs for that version, or look on support.oracle.com if you have an account.